# encrypt web.config with protectsection() for independent machine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to encrypt my web.config with section.sectioninformation.protectsection() and same web.config will run over 3 servers.

Is There any Possible way to accomplish this task.

Comment: As Per the following link  : 


   https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/877258/How-to-Encrypt-Web-config-Using-aspnet-regiis-exe

you will have to use **aspnet_regiis.exe**  . for example 
 `aspnet_regiis.exe -pef` command (Encryption)
This command encrypt a specific section in a specific hard drive location, so for example to encrypt “appSettings” section in site located at “C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\WebConfigEncryption” run:

`aspnet_regiis.exe -pef appSettings  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\WebConfigEncryption`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx

Command:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" C:\Projects\MachineRSA
```

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/976117/3850405
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5717845/3850405
[How to encrypt web.config section AND deploy to multiple servers with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369268/how-to-encrypt-web-config-section-and-deploy-to-multiple-servers-with-amazon-ela)

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this programmatically but using aspnet_regiis.exe, add the following section to the web.config file. N.B. Make sure the type information is correct - look at machine.config.

```
<configProtectedData defaultProvider="myRsaProvider">
   <providers>
      <add name="myRsaProvider"
           type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
           keyContainerName="myRsaKeys"
           useMachineContainer="true" />
   </providers>
</configProtectedData>
```

Create an exportable machine-level RSA key container

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "myRsaKeys"–exp
```

Grant permissions to the key container

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "myRsaKeys" "yourDomain\yourUsername"
```

Encrypt appSettings section of web.config in c:\temp\ using the custom RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, myRsaProvider

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "appSettings" c:\temp\ -prov "myRsaProvider"
```

Export the RSA key container

```
aspnet_regiis -px "myRsaKeys" myRsaKeys.xml -pri
```

Import the RSA key container on any machine where you install the web.config.

```
aspnet_regiis -pi "myRsaKeys" myRsaKeys.xml
```